# Strange behavior with NSObject Properties

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsobject

I have an `NSObject` that I am using to store/hold properties of an object, one of them being a "Name" property cast as an `NSString`. I am also pulling data from a SQLite DB for said object using the following:

```
- (void) getDataToDisplay:(NSString *)dbPath {

    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *queryOnStyle = [NSString stringWithFormat:
        @"SELECT WineId, Name FROM wine WHERE StyleId = %d", dataManager.styleId];

        const char *sql = [queryOnStyle UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

           while(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {

              Wine *w = [[Wine alloc] init]; 

              w.wineId = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 0);
              w.wineName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
                                (char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectstmt, 1)];

             [dataManager.wines addObject:w];
             [w release];
          }      
       }
    }
    else
       sqlite3_close(database); //Even though the open call failed, close the database connection to release all the memory.
    }
```

Wine being my object. If I were to log `w.wineName` at this point, there is no problem. The problem occurs later when I try to access the properties of the object from within the array, `dataManager.wines`, in a custom tableView. It suddenly treats my `wineName` as a `UIImageView` rather than an `NSString`...

I for the life of me cannot trace anything back to ever being cast as a `UIImageView` and have no idea why it would be setting just that property as such. Here is the code for my custom tableView:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark HorizontalTableViewDelegate methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfColumnsForTableView:(HorizontalTableView *)tableView {
    return [dataManager.wines count];
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(HorizontalTableView *)aTableView viewForIndex:(NSInteger)index {

    UIView *vw = [aTableView dequeueColumnView];
    if (!vw) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ColumnView" owner:self options:nil];
        vw = self.columnView;
        self.columnView = nil;

    }

 // Get the wineId from the array of wineId integers

 Wine *w = [dataManager.wines objectAtIndex:index];

 int tempWineId = w.wineId;
 NSString *tempWineName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", w.wineName];

 NSLog(@"%@", tempWineName); \\RETURNS TEMPWINENAME AS A UIIMAGEVIEW
 [w release];
 return vw;
}

- (CGFloat)columnWidthForTableView:(HorizontalTableView *)tableView {
 //TODO: This value needs to change if changed in IB
    return 209.0f;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: is w.wineName a retain'ed property ? This sounds a bit like the string is being auto released. Could you post the definition of the Wine object ?

Comment: What does your setter or property declaration for the `wineName` property look like?

Comment: Thanks a million for pointing that out. I am working in tandem with another developer and it was `@property(nonatomic,assign) NSString *wineName;` however, changing it to `@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *wineName;` works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in comments of question by RichB:

is `w.wineName` a retain'ed property ? This sounds a bit like the string is being auto released. Could you post the definition of the `Wine` object?